# CSS change where 100% is located

Tags: css, reactjs

I couldn't think of a very good title, but anyway, I'm using React to create a custom colour picker. I have most of the components including the sliders (hue and alpha) and the saturation "picker". I'm going to use the sliders as the example although the issue is similar for the saturation "picker".

The slider is made like this:

```
<div
    style={styles.sliderContainer}
    ref={r => { if (r) container = r; }}

    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
    onTouchMove={handleMove}
    onTouchStart={handleMove}
>
    <div style={styles.pointerContainer}>
        <div
            style={styles.pointer}
            ref={r => { if (r) pointer = r; }}
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

When the mouse moves, I pass into a function the event, the container ref and the pointer ref. I use it to calculate the hue value like this.

```
const calculateHue(event, container, pointer) = () => {
    const cWidth = container.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    const pWidth = pointer.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    let { x } = splitEvent(e);
    x = Math.max(0, Math.min(x - (pWidth / 2), cWidth - pWidth));

    return map(x, 0, cWidth - pWidth, 0, 360);
}
```

`map` is a function that maps an incoming value, in a certain range, to an output value between another range. `splitEvent` just gets the X and Y values of the mouse event.

Now, all that function does it calculate the hue value depening on where your mouse is. In order to actually move the "pointer" (aka the slider thumb), I need to use the hue value to get a position between 0 and 100%.

```
const h = calculateHue(....);
pointer.style.left = `${(h * 100) / 360}%`;
```

This works fine but I don't like the way it looks because, since the "left" position is based off the top-left corner, it allows the slider thumb to slide all the way off the edge, like this:

[imgur video](https://i.imgur.com/vNVK7IP.mp4)

What I am trying to go for is like the Google colour picker where the slider thumb can be halfway off each side:
[image]

But the issue is, what I want to avoid is duplicating code. I could pull this off by using basically identical code to whats in `calculateHue` with a few modifications, but I would really like to use the calculated hue value if possible.

I can get closer to what I want with this:

```
const h = calculateHue(....);
const pos = map(h, 0, 360,
    -(pointer.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2), //Start half way off ("half" being one radius of the pointer)
    container.getBoundingClientRect().width - (pointer.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2) //And finish half way off
);
```

This does work. The slider thumb can be halfway off on the left, and half way off on the right. However, it becomes out of sync with the mouse. If you watch the video above, it also happens - the pointer *should* stay in the centre of the mouse, but instead it gradually gets out of sync and the pointer moves further than the mouse. That's because I'm moving the pointer from 0% to 100% but the hue value is only being calculated from about 0% to 95%, hence the `cWidth - pWidth` in `calculateHue`.

So far, the only working way to do what I want is this:

```
const h = calculateHue(...);

const { width: cWidth, left } = container.getBoundingClientRect();
const pWidth = pointer.getBoundingClientRect().width;

let { x } = splitEvent(e);
x = Math.max(-(pWidth / 2), Math.min(x - (pWidth / 2) - left, cWidth - (pWidth / 2)));

pointer.style.left = `${x}px`;
```

Where I calculte both the hue, and the position using almost identical code.

I have tried using `transform` but with transform, 100% doesn't equal the width of the container, it's *just* the width of the pointer which means to actually transfrom 100% of the container, I would need to transform something like 1500%.

The point of this question is that, is it possible to make it so that 100% isn't actually 100% but more like 95%, so that the slider thumb doesn't move all the way off the slider, or even just a way to avoid duplicating that code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's okay that an example on pure js, I suppose you will get the main idea of how to restrict pointer go out of the color picker.

TL;DR The pointer's center should equals to the "click" position, you can do that by this:

```
colorPickerWidth * clickPosPercentage - pointerWidth / 2
```

then you have to restrict to pointer moves out of the color picker by setting min (0) and max (colorPickerWidth - pointerWidth) positons.

Also, there're two devices:

1. input[type="range"] allows you to receive the position of the pointer in the percentage of the wrapper width and gives you accessibility.
2. Animations based on CSS transform and opacity have better performance that animations based on "left", "top" etc.

```js
const lineEl = document.querySelector('.line');
const colorPickerEl = document.querySelector('.colorPicker');
const pointerEl = document.querySelector('.pointer');

colorPickerEl.addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => {
  const lineRect = lineEl.getBoundingClientRect();
  const pointerRect = pointerEl.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  pointerEl.style.setProperty('transform', `translateX(${calcPos(lineRect.width, target.value, pointerRect.width)}px)`);
})


function calcPos(lineW, colorX, pointerW) {
  const offset = Math.floor(pointerW / 2);
  const maxPos = lineW - pointerW;
  const pos = Math.floor(lineW * colorX / 100) - offset;

  return Math.min(Math.max(0, pos), maxPos);
}
```

```css
.line {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.colorPicker {
  opacity: .5;
  width: 100%;
}

.pointer {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <input class="colorPicker" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <button class="pointer" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it does work but it has an issue that I was trying to avoid where your mouse cursor isn't centred on the pointer for most of it. You can see it in [this](https://i.imgur.com/A3HBvxr.png) image. I would prefer it If the slider could stay centered in the pointer for the entire bar.